# Did you go to school to learn code? Advice on how to get better?

Tags: computer-science

I am interested in computer science and just coding in general, but sometimes I fear that I may not be good at it. Did you go to school to learn how to code? How did you learn? Also, if you could provide links for beginners and a list of languages that a beginner could start with, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: [Codecadamy](http://www.codecademy.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practice makes perfect. The only way you will become better at coding is to take a stab at it and keep going. I started learning how to code last summer, and I am glad to say that with late nights spent up coding, asking questions, and attending local seminars, I am getting there.

If you want to code, a good website to take a look at is codeacademy.com, as it allows you to take part in step by step activities to let you play around with and learn a few languages. I know that the local colleges in my city teach python, as it is built for readability and easy to use, speaking from experience. As a programming language, python is definitely something you might want to look into, as well as Ruby. (Both featured on codeacademy)

Additional notes:

- Sometimes something might not make sense to you. Make documentation and forums your best friend as they provide much resource to better your coding practices!
- It's not about how many languages you know, rather, how well you know a language.
- Different languages are used for different things. ex: HTML is used to create websites.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a question to be asked here but I will answer you anyway

programming can be challenging and frustrating at times, if you love it you will learn it. 
You can start learning in websites like

http://www.codecademy.com/
or

http://www.w3schools.com/

I recommend you to start learning HTML/CSS, they are the most basic for a beginner to know. I would say after you get your hands on it jump to C++. It is one of the hardest since it's a low level lang but once you get your hands on it you will find other languages easier to learn.

You can learn programming on your own you do not need school honestly. What you would need however are projects to work and practice on if you want to ever become good. You can learn 100 language but not improve in programming in general. syntax difference does not matter so much. It's understanding algorithms and programming concepts.

Good luck to you